# How to get Mounted Volume information using nio classes

Tags: java, windows, nio, mounted-volumes

I can use the unsupported  sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder classes to get the mounted volume information, but we would much rather use supported classes.  It seems like the nio classes should support this, but I can't figure out how.

I'm running with Java 8 on Win 7.
Using the code below, the ShellFolder classes give this info about the mounted volume:

```
  Z:\
  Title[0] = Name, val = MetrixAutomatedTestDataFiles (\\fcna02) (Z:)
  Title[1] = Size, val = Network Drive
  Title[2] = Item type, val = 1.46 TB
  Title[3] = Date modified, val = 645 GB
  Title[4] = Date created, val = NTFS
  Title[5] = Date accessed, val = 
  Title[6] = Attributes, val = \\fcna02\MetrixAutomatedTestDataFiles
  Title[7] = Offline status, val = ‎57%
  Title[8] = Offline availability, val = ‎645 GB free of 1.46 TB
```

item 6 is the information I need.

When I try to use the nio FileStore class, it fails to provide anything other than the most basic information.

```
   (Z:)                   1572025140    895400568    676624572
    (Z:)
        attr=owner, Supported
        attr=owner, NOT VALID
        attr=dos, Supported
        attr=dos, NOT VALID
        attr=acl, Supported
        attr=acl, NOT VALID
        attr=basic, Supported
        attr=basic, NOT VALID
        attr=user, Supported
        attr=user, NOT VALID
```

Attributes that get supportsFileAttributeView of true, aren't valid.

```
package com.metrixsoftware.build;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.util.Set;
import sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder;
import sun.awt.shell.ShellFolderColumnInfo;

public class Junk1 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--- Using ShellFolder ---");
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();

        for (File file : roots) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                ShellFolder sf = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(file);
                ShellFolderColumnInfo[] cols = sf.getFolderColumns();

                for (int idx = 0; (idx < cols.length); idx++) {
                    ShellFolderColumnInfo col = cols[idx];
                    Object val = sf.getFolderColumnValue(idx);
                    if (val != null) {
                        System.out.println("Title[" + idx + "] = " + col.getTitle() + ", val = " + val);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(" ERROR: " + e.getMessage());

            } finally {

            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n--- Using FileStore from Default FileSystems ---");
        Set<String> attributes = FileSystems.getDefault().supportedFileAttributeViews();

        for (FileStore fstore : FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
            try {
                long total = fstore.getTotalSpace() / 1024;
                long used = (fstore.getTotalSpace() - fstore.getUnallocatedSpace()) / 1024;
                long avail = fstore.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
                System.out.format("%-20s %12d %12d %12d%n", fstore, total, used, avail);

                System.out.println("\t" + fstore);
                for (String attr : attributes) {
                    try {
                        if (fstore.supportsFileAttributeView(attr)) {
                            System.out.println("\t\tattr=" + attr + ", Supported");
                            try {
                                System.out.println("\t\tattr=" + attr + ", value=" + fstore.getAttribute(attr));
                            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
                                System.out.println("\t\tattr=" + attr + ", NOT VALID");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("\t\tattr=" + attr + ", NOT SUPPORTED");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("\t\tattr=" + attr + ", INVALID");
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(" ERROR: " + e.getMessage());

            } finally {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there ANY way to use nio to get the volume mount information?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not provide an inbuilt way to access the mount information. You will have to use `Runtime.exec()` to run system commands such as [Windows Diskpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart).